# Selecionar dados e exibir

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problemas para consultar o MySQL de uma forma simples.

Já tenho um arquivo no `includes` de conexão ao banco que funciona normalmente.
Porem na pagina de consulta não estou conseguindo exibi-los.

O [código que achei no Google](https://gist.github.com/Alkun/a5d83e2a1003a8defbef).

1 - Não estou entendo a parte do *loop* `while`. Ele cria uma variável dentro do próprio *loop*? (`$clientes`)

2 - O que é `fetch_object()`?

Queria um meio mais simples?

Comment: Já que está retornando aos estudos agora... aconselho a já estudar PDO. :)

Comment: Os passos para realizar uma consulta no banco são: 1 - transformar a string sql em uma consulta. 2 - Passar esse 'resultado' para a função/método que extrai as linhas do banco, geralmente é necessario utilizar um for/while para percorrer todas as linhas.

Comment: Onde posso encontrar esse material pra estudos PDO? você conhece algum lugar?

Poderia dar um exemplo de consulta em códigos para eu ver se entendo?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly você não precisa fazer isto, PDO não vai te ajudar em nada.Veja as respostas, e avise se ainda falta algo para entender melhor.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly não conselhei PDO por ajudar em sua dúvida, aconselhei pelo fato de ser mais limpo e suportar diversos bancos de dados; http://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190737/what-is-difference-between-mysql-mysqli-and-pdo

Comment: @RafaelAcioly Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Não tem forma mais simples que isso.

Sim, ele cria uma variável quando ele entra no `while` e reaproveita esta variável todas as vezes que ele passa pelo `while` atribuindo uma novo valor obtido do banco de dados. A função do `fetch_object()` é justamente trazer uma nova linha do banco de dados - associado a variável `$resultado` e o resultado no caso é um objeto que precisa ser atribuído a uma variável, no caso a `$clientes`. Se o não há mais dados para trabalhar o `fetch_object()` retorna `false` indicando que o laço deve encerrar.

Daí dentro do laço você pode usar esta variável para acessar seus membros que são justamente os campos que vieram do banco de dados se acordo com a *query* usada anteriormente.

```
<?php 
require_once('includes/conexao.php'); //pegou dados da conexão
 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM clientes'; //prepara a query a ser mandada para o banco de dados

$resultado = $con->query($sql); //executa a query e guarda o resultado em $resultado
//guarda uma linha do resultado em $clientes (este será um objeto cujos membros serão as 
//colunas da tabela clientes, será false se não tiver novas linhas)
while ($clientes = $resultado->fetch_object()) { //cada passagem aqui pega uma linha nova
    echo $clientes->nome; //pega o membro nome da linha atual que o PHP está avaliando
    echo $clientes->telefone;
} //aqui termina o processamento de uma linha e vai tentar a próxima linha no while
?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/GetDataAndPrint.php).

Answer (score 1):

Uma das vantagens das linguagens dinâmicas é que ela proporciona construções mais flexiveis que as linguagens de estaticas.

O while funciona em duas partes, primeira verifica-se `fetch_object()` é diferente de false, caso seja(existe um resultado do banco) vem a segunda parte a que é feita a atribuição do resultado a variável `$clientes`, isso ocorre devido as [regras de precedências dos operadores](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) do PHP.

O operador de atribuição é um dos que menos tem precendência, por isso é feita a verificação do valor do while(true ou false) e em caso positivo é feita a atribuição.

```
        2- passo          1 - passo
                     false/ou qualquer coisa
while ($clientes = $resultado->fetch_object()) {
  echo $clientes->nome;
  echo $clientes->telefone;
}
```

Que pode ser interpretado como:

```
while ($clientes = false) //Não entra no while

                           true
while ($clientes = $resultado->fetch_object())// Faz a atribuição
```

Answer (score 1):

1. O while está atribuindo o retorno da função "**fetch_object**" a variável "**$clientes**"
   (**dica**: use "$cliente").
2. A função "fetch_object" retorna como **objeto** uma linha de resultado da query, por isso; somada ao while, ela faz com que você acesse cada linha do resultado da query.